# Compiled _ssl with MSVC, host application crashes (not in debugger!)

Tags: python, windows, debugging, visual-c++, access-violation

I'm trying to compile the `_ssl` module on Windows for Python 2.6 using the MSVC compiler, because the Python runtime embedded into the host application is built with this compiler and of this version. The runtime does not come with native ssl-support on Windows however, not because it is not supported, but because (among an official statement) licenses have not yet been checked to be compatible with the closed-source application.

I've downloaded the [CPython 2.6.8 source](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.6.8/) from the Python homepage and extracted `_ssl.c` and `socketmodule.h` (required include by the ssl module source) into a separate folder. I've also downloaded the [openssl-for-windows](http://code.google.com/p/openssl-for-windows/) win32 builds in order to linke it with the ssl module source.

My build-commands are the following:

```
cl /I"C:\path\to\host\python\runtime\include" /I"include/" _ssl.c /Fo"_ssl.obj" /c
link _ssl.obj /DLL "C:\path\to\host\python\runtime\libs\python26.lib" lib/libeay32.lib lib/ssleay32.lib Ws2_32.lib /OUT:_ssl.pyd
```

`libeay32.lib` and `ssleay32.lib` are from the openssl-for-windows distribution. The module compiles fine and outputs an 88KB shared library.

**Problem**

When I start the host application and run a command invoking the Python runtime running code importing and using the recently compiled `_ssl` module, the application crashes. The host application has its own kind of exception handler writing a bugreport when crashing.

```
Exception
{
    ExceptionNumber = 0xC0000005
    ExceptionText = "ACCESS_VIOLATION"
    Address = 0x01A27058
    Thread = 4776
    Last_Error = 0x00000000
}
```

The call-stack at the point of the exception does not end in any Python related procedures. I assume that something incorrect happened before that triggers the error at this place.

**Weirdness**

When I run the application from the Win32 Debugger (WinDbg), this error does *not* happen and everything runs fine.

**Question**

What am I doing wrong with compiling the `_ssl` module, or what could trigger this exception?

**Additional Information**

- The embedded Python runtime is the following: `2.6.4 (r264:75706, Mar  6 2012, 02:32:04) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)]`

Comment: The VS C compiler uses different C runtime libraries for Debug and Release builds, which may be a clue to both the original problem and the weirdness in the debugger. Basically _everything_, including the openssl-for-windows distribution and Python itself, has to be compiled to use the same version of the runtime library. They all have to be compiled with the same version of VS, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The crash finally was due to a bug in the host application. This bug could however only occure, when data was fetched from the web, which was only possible with the ssl module.